# Cannot find App Attest Capability in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase-app-check

According to the App Check Firebase Documentation, it is said to add the App Attest capability to your app.
However, I am not able to find any such capability in XCode. Any insights on this?

Note: We have enabled capability in the provision profiles

Documentation Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/app-attest-provider#install-sdk

[Screenshot of Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTgci.png)

Answer (score 4):

A Firebase developer here.

Currently you need to set [App Attest environment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_devicecheck_appattest-environment) to `production` in your app entitlements file. You can achieve it by adding the key directly to the  file or you can follow the steps below (relevant for Xcode 12.5):

1. Open `Signing & Capabilities` tab in the settings of your app target
2. Press `+ Capability` button
3. Select `App Attest`([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql6CP.png))
4. Open the corresponding entitlements file usually named like `YourAppTargetName.entitlements`
5. Set value `production` for `App Attest Environment` key([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTMwB.png))

Sorry if the docs don't contain enough details, we will try to make them more clear.

Comment: I have added the App Attest capability. Then when I set the `production` environment in the `.entitlements` file, the App Attest capability will disappear upon saving file. Then when I added the capability again, the environment changed to `development` again. Then the whole cycle repeated. So frustrating!

Comment: Hi. I'm developing a macOS application and I don't see the `App Attest` when I click on `+ Capability`. I'm running XCode Version 13.1. 
Can we add AppCheck to a macOS app and distribute it?

Comment: same here, after adding App Attest, if I close Xcode and then reopen there is no App Attest. This is breaking CI builds too....

Comment: same here @Zenko

Comment: how to fix it??

Comment: you must have enrolled in the Apple Developer Program