# firebaseappcheck.googleapis exchangeDeviceCheckToken error 400 with message "App not registered" and status FAILED_PRECONDITION

Tags: xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-app-check

I run my app on XCode 14.0. The app runs but I get an error:

```
2022-10-28 17:55:47.5832 xxx34-0400 x[14690:980363] 8.14.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] AppCheck failed: 'The operation couldn’t be completed. Too many attempts. Underlying error: The operation couldn’t be completed. The server responded with an error: 
 - URL: https://firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/xxxxx/apps/xxxxxx:ios:xxxxx:exchangeDeviceCheckToken 
 - HTTP status code: 400 
 - Response body: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "App not registered: xxxx:ios:xxxxx.",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
}
```

The app is already registered in Firebase Console's App Check. I re-downloaded my GoogleService-Info. Still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you enabled DeviceCheck on Apple Developer?

- Keys for DeviceCheck: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list

and upload the key on Firebase console,

- https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<your_project>/appcheck/apps

---

For AppAttest, you need to add it to capability on Identifier

- Identifier for App Attest: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list

then you add it on Xcode project.
(ref: [Cannot find App Attest Capability in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68650909/cannot-find-app-attest-capability-in-xcode))

(if you enable App Attest on the `Identifier`, existing `profiles` will be invalidated)
https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list